# Flutter - Notify child pages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-pageview

I have a Parent page, that contains a `PageView`, like this :

```
class _ParentState extends State<ParentOverview> {

  String title = "" ;

  List<String>  pageTitles = [
    "Page 1",
    "Page 2",
  ] ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Expenses"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onTap: (() {
                // TODO
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          ChildPage1(),
          ChildPage2(),
        ],
        onPageChanged: ((selectedPage) {
          setState(() {
            title = pageTitles[selectedPage] ;
          });
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

The children of `PageView` are `StatefulWidget`.
This Parent page contains an `AppBar` with a button that is used to reload.
When clicking on this button, I want to make a call that reload the data contained inside Page1 and Page2.

How can I achieve that ?
I have been told to use `Provider`, but is this the best way to do that ?